# What means something=something == number ? expression in Java

Tags: java, android

private int nColumns = 1;

public void onClick(View view) {

```
            nColumns = nColumns == 1 ? 2 : 1; //Cannot understand this line.
```

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: This is equivalent to
if (nColumns == 1) {
   nColumns = 2;
}
else {
  nColumns = 1;
}

Comment: Great! thanks a lot!

Comment: delete your question to recover you rep

Comment: @KeithNicholas i tried but says i cannot because others have invested time answering or something like that. Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 1):

It is a ternary operator.
The part `(nColumns == 1) ? 2 : 1;` basically means if `nColumns` is equal to `1` then the first one, `2`, is selected and else the latter, `1`.
That value is then stored in the same variable `nColumns`.

So if it is equal to 1 then it gets 2 else it gets 1.

It does the same as the following:

```
if(nColumns == 1)
  nColumns = 2;
else
  nColumns = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

if the number of nColumns is 1 return 2 else return 1 and assign it to it slef which is nColumns.

```
if(nColumns==1)
   nColumns=2;
else
   nColumns=1;
```